# Where is 1.1.1.1 really located?

Tags: router, ipv4, nat, ping

I'm courious how this works:

When ping-ing 1.1.1.1 I get results of roundabout 15 ms, where 1.1.1.1 is located in California, according to iplocation.net.

When ping-ing a random ISP from California I get results of roundabout 170ms.

Since I'm testing this from Europe and (assuming the ISP's ping response isn't extremely slow) there is a 10-fold increase in delay, I was wondering how this works.

If I do tracert to both addresses, the result shows, that 1.1.1.1 terminates in my country, while the ISP terminates in California.

My guess:
1.1.1.1 has servers in my country and uses a special configuration in routers inbetween me and their servers to route me to the local instance of 1.1.1.1.

-> If so, this means that there are cases, where (in IPv4) multiple servers with the same public IPv4 can exist within the (global) internet, as long as there are routers in between and the IP-address-ranges between these routers don't allow for 1.1.1.1 to exist (similar to everyone of us having their 192.168.1.0/24 network at home).

I Imagine something like this (extremely simplified):

(1.1.1.1 California) & (CaliforniaISP) ---- Router A ----- RestOfTheInternet ----- Router B ---- 1.1.1.1 LocalToMe ---- myISP ---- Me

-> Am I right with my guess and my interpretation?